# How add startup scripts to new systemd based os whose traditional scripts are all gone in init.d?

Tags: linux, fedora, systemd

I don not know what to do to add a startup script.

Traditional scripts are all gone.

Replaced by `livesys  livesys-late  netconsole  network` in `init.d`

and

`K01livesys-late  K50netconsole  K90network  K99livesys` in `rc[0-6].d`

Comment: Have you looked up how startup scripts are handled in systemd?

Comment: I wrote a basic intro to systemd that might help you, here: https://www.darkcoding.net/software/the-joy-of-systemd/

Comment: @GrahamKing Nice! Thanks!